# Argument labels '(format:, matchesArray:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I am doing a CloudKit query, in which I exclude any entities with the 'creatorUserRecordID' equal to any Id's stored within an array called matchesArray, I have done this by using NSPredicate (along with other custom predicates):

`let predicate4:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "creatorUserRecordID IN %@", matchesArray:[Array])`

However, I am getting the following error:

Argument labels '(format:, matchesArray:)' do not match any available overloads.

Does anyone know how to fix this, and not query entitles which creators ID is stored within the matches array?

Comment: How is this related to jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were trying to write this,

```
  let predicate4:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "creatorUserRecordID IN %@", matchesArray)
```